# MyBatis Case insensitive deserialization

Tags: java, jackson, mybatis, ibatis, jackson-databind

I would like to have some robustness when deserializing Enums from a database. Basically, entries in the database `"alpha", "Alpha", "ALPHA"` should all be deserialized to the `ALPHA` enum. How can this be done with `MyBatis 3.4.6`?

The Java enum class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public enum Greek {
    @JsonProperty("Alpha") ALPHA,
    @JsonProperty("Beta") BETA
}
```

The MyBatis mapper and Service

```
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;
import java.util.List;

@Mapper
public interface EZRatingMapper {
    List<Greek> getGreeks();
}

public class GreekService {
    private final GreekMapper greekMapper;

    @Inject
    public GreekService(GreekMapper dbMapper){
        this.greekMapper = dbMapper;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Greek> getGreeks() {
        return greekMapper.getGreeks();
    }
}
```

The MyBatis xml:

> ```
> <select id="getGreeks" resultType="Greek">
>     SELECT greek FROM `greek_table`
> </select>
> ```

For the deserialization of Jsons, I achieved the desired robustness with `Jackson 2.9.1` like:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS, true);
Greek greek = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Greek.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option to modify the SQL query.
Convert the enum value to upper case in the query:

```
<select id="getGreeks" resultType="Greek">
    SELECT UPPER(greek) greek FROM `greek_table`
</select>
```

Another option that cannot be directly used in this case but can be used in other cases is to use custom type handler.

In current mybatis version (3.5.0) it is not possible to specify the type handler for the main entity that is returned so for the query where enum values are returned the custom type handler can't be used. But in many cases when enum is the field of the object that is returned by the mapper it works.

You can create your own type handler something like:

```
public class GreekEnumTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<Greek> {

  @Override
  public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, E parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
    if (jdbcType == null) {
      ps.setString(i, parameter.name());
    } else {
      ps.setObject(i, parameter.name(), jdbcType.TYPE_CODE);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public E getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
    String s = rs.getString(columnName);
    return s == null ? null : Greek.valueOf(s.toUpperCase());
  }

  @Override
  public E getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    String s = rs.getString(columnIndex);
    return s == null ? null : Greek.valueOf(s.toUpperCase());
  }

  @Override
  public E getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    String s = cs.getString(columnIndex);
    return s == null ? null : Greek.valueOf(s.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

And then use it in the mapper like this:

```
<resultMap id="entityMap" type="Entity">
  <id property="id" column="id"/>
  <result property="greek" column="greek" typeHandler="GreekEnumTypeHandler"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="getEntity" resultMap="entityMap">
    SELECT id, greek FROM entity
</select>
```